# gets not taking the password

Tags: c, fgets

In the code below in lesson2() i have used a password to enter the function but when i enter the function it does not takes in the passord and says incorrect password.By not taking in the password,i mean to say that i have used gets but its waiting for me to input a password.please dont tell me not to use gets!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dos.h>
int mistakes=0,mistakes_length,len;
char temp[100];
void lesson1(void);
void lesson2(void);
void result(void);
void main(void)
{
    int choice;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a lesson number to practise:1-10 \n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        lesson1();
        result();
        break;
        case 2:
        lesson2();
        result();
        break;
        default:
        printf("You did not entered a valid choice program quitting..\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    getch();
}
void lesson1(void)
{
    int i;
    char str1[100]="testing the typing tutor if it works";
    mistakes_length=5;
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(25,2);
    puts("Welcome to lesson 1");
    puts(str1);
    len=strlen(str1);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        temp[i]=getche();
        if(strncmpi(&str1[i],&temp[i],1))//does not match
        {
            mistakes++;
            sound(100);
            delay(1000);
            nosound();

        }
    }
    getch();
}
void result(void)
{
    printf("Your statsistics are as under:\nYou performed this lesson with %d mistakes\n",mistakes);
    if(mistakes>=mistakes_length)
        {
                printf("\n Your typing is very bad");//allow anything to be typed with any mistake in lesson 1

        }
        if(mistakes>3&&mistakes<5)
        {
            printf("Bad!,You need to practise this excercise more\n");
        }
        if(mistakes>=1&&mistakes<=3)
        {
            printf("Good!you can still do better\n");
        }
        if(mistakes==0)
        {
            printf("Excellent!You are qualified for the next lesson\n");
            printf("The next lessons password is \n\t\t\t:12345");
        }
}

void lesson2(void)
{
    char password[]="12345",str2[]="My name is khan and i am not a criminal";
    int i;
    mistakes=0,mistakes_length=0,
    printf("Enter password:\n");
    gets(temp);
    if(strcmp(temp,password))
    {
        gotoxy(20,25);
        printf("Wrong Password,Program Quitting.\n");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    gotoxy(25,25);
    printf("Password Accpted!");
    getch();
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(25,2);
    printf("Welcome to lesson 2\n");
    printf("Type the text shown below:\n");
    puts(str2);
    len=strlen(str2);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        temp[i]=getche();
        if(strncmp(&str2[i],&temp[i],1));
        {
            mistakes++;
        }

    }
    getch();
}
```

I think that it is the scanf and gets together making a problem!

Comment: Don't use gets. And whatever book you are learning to write code like this from, burn it.

Comment: I am learing myslef.Whats wrong with my code dear?

Comment: Can you please post the output that you are seeing?  I am confused regarding the exact problem you are seeing.

Comment: You should `fgets` instead of `gets` as already said, from the manual of `gets`:

"Never  use  gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead."

Comment: its skipping the part to ask password.It says enter password and then directly says wrong password without taking in the password

Comment: @fahad: It is full of proprietary library calls from an antique compiler targeting an obsolete 16 bit operating system. 15 years on from the release of Windows 95 it is not a good idea to *start out* writing code for a target that is only *simulated* in Windows to support legacy applications.

Comment: I was told that it is the best way to understand how things work in any language.C language is the basic

Comment: If you were aiming to be a mechanic, would you learn by repairing a 1932 Ford?

Comment: @ed :Its more about understanding how things work.It helps you what actually is happening behind in C++ and java.Like u might have been taught the false theories of previous scientists who used to say bla bla and and you might be wondering that why am i being taught that.I dont know about anyone else but i myself think like that,that why am i being taught something which is wrong and old.You can not proceed without a good background of things!

Comment: then start by learning assembly. or even better machine opcodes

Comment: It is not the C language that is the problem, it is the C compiler you are using and the obsolete non-standard library you are relying on.  The libraries and the C language are distinct entities, by using obsolete libraries for an obsolete OS on an obsolete compiler nothing you are learining will be portble to modern systems.

Comment: I know that but i am a university student and i have to follow RULES :/ DO WHAT YOU ARE TAUGHT ! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that prior to calling gets(), you have called `scanf("%d",&choice);` (in `main()`).  The problem with this is that console input is *line oriented*.  This means that although you are only waiting for a number to be entered the user has to enter a complete line ending in *newline*.  The %d format specifier only consumes the digit characters leaving the rest of the line in the buffer to be used by the next console input call; which in this case is gets() which sees the *newline* in the buffer and returns an empty string without waiting for further input.

A solution:

```
scanf("%d",&choice);
while(getchar() != '\n' ) { /*no nothing*/}
```

Comment: But where is that new line which scanf skips? I dont get that a new line is skipped by scanf as i never gave a newline as input in scanf

Comment: @fahad: Yes you did!  You typed "2" followed by [Enter].  The [Enter] key inserts a '\n' character.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you are seeing is in fact coming from the main method.

The scanf() call that you make is only looking for "%d" rather than "%d\n".

Therefore, you enter the number 2 in order to try test 2, and must press enter before that value gets to the program.  Since scanf is not trying to match it, that newline remains as part of the input stream and thus is passed directly to gets() within the next function.

Therefore, if you change the string within scanf inside the main function, you should see the code start working.

Now on another note (and I know that you asked us not to but...) you really shouldn't use gets().  In order to switch to fgets, just replace gets(temp) with fgets(temp,99,stdin).  That 99 is any number that is less than the size of the temp buffer you have made, which in this case has size 100.

Comment: "%d\n" would only work is the user entered "2<newline>".  It they entered "2abcdef<newline>" for example it would still fail in the same way.  I'd also suggest `fgets(temp,sizeof(temp),stdin)`, but that is still not a direct replacement for gets() since fgets() retains the '\n', whereas gets() discards it; so additional code is required to overwrite the '\n' with '\0'.  Still not hard to wrap in a function so there is no real excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing temp like this: `printf("[%s]\n", temp);` after the `gets(temp);` to see what is saved in `temp`. It may takes as input a previous given input from `lesson1` function?

If this is the case, something like this maybe will fix the problem:

```
char other_tmp[5];
gets(other_tmp);
gets(temp);
```

although in such a case you should better correct the `lesson1` function instead.

Answer (score -1):

it supposed to work.
edit your code:

```
int r = gets(temp);
printf("returned: %d, Entered: %s\n", r, temp);
```

and post here the result

Comment: That is not an answer and perhaps should have been just a comment.  Moreover, fahad would be far better off using his compiler's source level debugger that printing out variables.

Comment: @Clifford ... From his question I think he just started learning, so I guess he wouldn't know how to use a debugger

Comment: @fahad: What compiler are you using?  Looks like a Borland library, all Borland C/C++ compilers since Turbo C++ 1.01 in 1991 included a debugger.  There are more modern free compilers that have far better debuggers - no excuses.

Comment: I dont have a very good idea about debugging.I searched many a times but did not found any debugger.I use borland turbo c 3

Comment: @fahad: There is no such thing as Turbo C 3; there was a Turbo C++ 3.0 (released in 1991).  I Googled a screen shot of the IDE and can clearly see "Debug" in the menu strip.  That is where to start.  You can also run Turbo Debugger stand-alone.